# Magento friendly multilanguage link

Tags: magento

I have a question about multilanguage on magento.
My site (www.tucanotest.it) have english and italian and a lot of other languages.

If i switch from italian to english this url appear 'http://www.tucanotest.it/index.php/?___store=english&___from_store=italia'
There is a way to convert this link to http://www.tucanotest.it/en/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use subdomain instead.

You would have to update the Base URL in the Configuration for each Store view:

`GENERAL > Web > Secure` and `GENERAL > Web > Unsecure`

Then you would have to set such environment variables in your .htaccess:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Host "^nl\.website\.be$"    MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store MAGE_RUN_CODE=nl_be
SetEnvIfNoCase Host "^fr\.website\.be$"    MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store MAGE_RUN_CODE=fr_be
```

First you have to search what is your Store View Code, you can find them in `System > Manage Stores` then click on the Store View name.
If your Store View code for your english view is `en_it` for example, you would have to write that in the .htaccess:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Host "^en\.tucanotest\.it$"    MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store MAGE_RUN_CODE=en_it
```

Comment: thx, i'll try. THere is no way to have www.tucanotest.it/en/?

Comment: The way you want to do it sounds complicated to me because magento will think /en/ is the code of a module. I don't say there is no way but I think my example is much easier to setup.

Comment: Can you explain or expand the answer? I tried but without result.

Comment: first have you created the subdomain(s)?